# Unable to invoke primary constructor of data class - MongoDB Kotlin Driver

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, jvm

I'm not sure why exactly I'm getting this error. Everything seems fine, check the code below.

This is my model class:

```
@Serializable
actual data class User(
    @SerialName(value = "_id")
    actual val id: String = "",
    actual val username: String = "",
    actual val password: String = ""
)
```

This is my code:

```
override suspend fun checkUserExistence(user: User): User? {
    return try {
        userCollection
            .find(
                Filters.and(
                    Filters.eq(User::username.name, user.username),
                    Filters.eq(User::password.name, user.password)
                )
            ).firstOrNull()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        context.logger.error("checkUserExistence ERROR")
        context.logger.error(e.message.toString())
        null
    }
}
```

This is the error:

> [Thread-16] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.operation - Unable to retry the
> operation find due to the error
> "org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Unable to
> invoke primary constructor of User data class" 2023-09-09 07:33:26.780
> [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-4] ERROR ktor.application - checkUserExistence
> ERROR 2023-09-09 07:33:26.780 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-4] ERROR
> ktor.application - Unable to invoke primary constructor of User data
> class

Comment: Not sure if you have fully resolved this but in my case I had the same error and I fixed it, here is what I found : Both the Kotlin data class and MongoDB doc have to be in complete parity and neither of them should have any additional or missing fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the issue here was the `@SerialName(value = "_id")` annotation. My best guess is that when a mongodb tries to construct a User object, it doesn't recognize the `_id` field name which is stored in the database, instead it uses the `id` as the name of the field, which is not correct? Not sure tho, but mongo folks should take a look into that. Hope this answer helps someone as well. :)

Comment: You say the issue was the `@SerialName(value = "_id")` annotation, but you don't explain how you fixed it. The rest of your comment sounds like maybe you changed it to `@SerialName(value = "id")`, but I'm not sure. Could you edit your answer and elaborate? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by annotating with `@BsonProperty` e.g

```kotlin
@Serializable
actual data class PostLight(
    @SerialName("_id")
    @BsonProperty("_id")
    actual val id: String = ObjectId().toHexString(),
    actual val date: Long,
    actual val title: String,
    actual val subtitle: String,
    actual val thumbnail: String,
    actual val category: String,
)
```